# Extracting first column that meets certain criteria for each row

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I will try to explain what I am doing the best I can it is kind of confusing but I'll give it a shot. Essentially I start with 2 data frames. Each one containing a unique row per person and two items per user as columns. My goal is to turn this into 1 data frame with one unique row per user and the first item from each of the two data frames upon the condition that the items do not repeat. For example if for customer 1 in the first data frame his items are "a" and "d" and in the second data frame his items are "a" and "c", I would want the final data frame to be "a" and "c" for this customer. I have written an apply that does this however when I perform this on roughly 160,000 rows it takes quite a bit of time. I was hoping someone would be able to come up with a more efficient solution to my problem.

```
d1 <- data.frame(id = c("1", "2", "3"), stringsAsFactors = F)
r1 <- data.frame(i1 = c("a", "b", "c"), i2 = c("d", "e", "f"), stringsAsFactors = F)
rownames(r1) = d1$id
r2 <- data.frame(i1 = c("a", "c", "f"), i2 = c("c", "t", "l"), stringsAsFactors = F)
rownames(r2) = d1$id

dFinal <- data.frame(id = d1$id, r1 = "", r2 = "", stringsAsFactors = F)

dFinal$r1 = apply(dFinal, 1, function(x){r1[rownames(r1) == x["id"], "i1"]})
dFinal$r2 = apply(dFinal, 1, function(x){r2[rownames(r2) == x["id"], which(!r2[rownames(r2) == x["id"],c("i1","i2")] %in% x["r1"])[1]]})
```

Comment: Hm, I could see merge working however the one part I am not sure of with merge would be how to chose the correct columns after the merge. Lets say that r1 and r2 had id as a column instead of a rownames.                 `dInter <- merge(r1,r2, by = "id")`                                                                  But then I'm not sure how to replicate the logic from the apply where I only chose the correct columns

Comment: In your example, why *a* and *c* and not *a* and *d*? Is there another criteria?

Comment: @Parfait I want to take the first available column from each data frame that isn't present in the previous data frame. So from the first data frame the first column is chosen which is _a_ then for the same id in the second data frame the choices are _a_ and _c_, since a has been used for the first data frame then _c_ is chosen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the accepted answer as it worked perfectly! However it gave me an idea to use ifelse. While it doesn't work any better or worse than the accepted answer it was a little easier for me to wrap my head around when adding more columns or data frames.

```
  dfInt <- cbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)
  dfInt$R1_Final <- dfInt$R1_1
  dfInt$R2_Final <- ifelse(dfInt$R1_Final == dfInt$R2_1,
                               dfInt$R2_2,
                               dfInt$R2_1)
  dfInt$R3_Final <- ifelse(dfInt$R1_Final != dfInt$R3_1 & dfInt$R2_Final != dfInt$R3_1,
                               dfInt$R3_1,
                               ifelse(dfInt$R2_Final != dfInt$R3_2,
                                      dfInt$R3_2,
                                      dfInt$R3_3))
  dfInt$R4_Final <- ifelse(dfInt$R1_Final != dfInt$R4_1 & dfInt$R2_Final != dfInt$R4_1 & dfInt$R3_Final != dfInt$R4_1,
                               dfInt$R4_1,
                               ifelse(dfInt$R2_Final != dfInt$R4_2 & dfInt$R3_Final != dfInt$R4_2,
                                      dfInt$R4_2,
                                      ifelse(dfInt$R3_Final != dfInt$R4_3,
                                             dfInt$R4_3,
                                             dfInt$R4_4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would the following do what you're looking for:

```
# Keep only first column of first data.frame
df <- cbind(d1,r1,r2)[,-3]
names(df) <- c("id","r1_final","r2_i1","r2_i2")
df$r2_final <- df$r2_i1

# Keep only second column of second data.frame
# if the value in the first column is found in first data.frame
df[df$r1_final == df$r2_i1,"r2_final"] <- df[df$r1_final == df$r2_i1,"r2_i2"]
df_final <- df[,c("id","r1_final","r2_final")]
print(df_final)

  id r1_final r2_final
1  1        a        c
2  2        b        c
3  3        c        f
```

**Edit:**
OP asked for a solution if there were four data.frames instead of 2 like in the example, here is some code that I haven't tested but it should work with two additional columns

```
df$r2_final <- df$r2_i1
df$r3_final <- df$r3_i1
df$r4_final <- df$r4_i1

df[df$r1_final == df$r2_i1,"r2_final"] <- df[df$r1_final == df$r2_i1,"r2_i2"]
df[df$r3_i1 %in% c(df$r1_final,df$r2_final),"r3_final"] <- df[df$r3_i1 %in% c(df$r1_final,df$r2_final),"r3_i2"]
df[df$r4_i1 %in% c(df$r1_final,df$r2_final,df$r3_final),"r4_final"] <- df[df$r4_i1 %in% c(df$r1_final,df$r2_final,df$r3_final),"r4_i2"]
df_final <- df[,c("id","r1_final","r2_final","r3_final","r4_final")]
```

Comment: This may be a great idea! Only edit the rows where the value is repeated. I do think this solves the problem I posted, but I have one follow up if you don't mind me asking. In the actual problem I have 4 r_final columns I'm trying to fill in. I'm guessing this would work if I just extended your answer, but I'm not sure what that would look like if say I wanted r3_final to not be equal to r1_final and r2_final.

Comment: I added an edit, if you have even more or variable numbers of data.frames to work with, then I would write a function that you can use on every number of columns. I could imagine to work with a loop that loops over the different data.frames / columns. Don't loop / apply over the rows if you have many rows, that will make the code slower.